# SQL Server Ignoring Connection String Parameters

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-2016, connection-pooling, wcf-data-services

We have a legacy application which we are upgrading to SQL Server 2016.

The connection is created as below:

```
var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
sqlConn.Open();
```

Our connection string contains the following values (as well as database server and so on):

```
Connection Timeout=600;Min Pool Size=10;Max Pool Size=200
```

However, at runtime we can see that these values are being ignored.

The process logs it's current threadcount as it runs a large number of queries coming in from client requests. When the threadcount goes over 100 (the default Max Pool Size) we will shortly after get a connection pool timeout after 15 seconds (the connection pool timeout default):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8

Code is compiled as .NET Framework 4.6.2, but running on a Server with .NET 4.8 installed.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Previous version of the code initalised a SqlConnection without a connection string, and then added the Connection String before calling Open()

Comment: Did you check if you create SqlConnections elsewhere in your code where you don't explicitly specify a Max Pool Size?

Comment: You are correct. The code has a strange nested connection behaviour where it first attempts a connection to a different DB with a different connection string.